# WPF Datagrid tabbing adds row but loses focus

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus, cell

So I have a WPF datagrid, and it has 2 columns (Name and Quantity) and I want to enter the following:

Name       Quantity

Apples       2

Bananas       3

Watermelon     1

So I go to the first cell, type 'Apples' hit TAB, which takes me to the second column in edit mode, so I type '2', hit TAB. Notice that TAB adds a new row but takes the focus away from the datagrid.

Instead I want TAB to go to the second row in Edit Mode so I can type 'Bananas' on the first column right away. And I can just hit TAB and keep typing and add more items.

I've tried every possible way I can find to make this happen but no luck so far... Anybody willing to help me THANKS a lot!

Comment: try adding KeyboardNavigation.Tabnavigation="Local" in your datagrid

Comment: it didn't do it...:(

Answer (score 0):

you can see below answer for your reference as it is showing same scenarion.

[DataGrid select last cell programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543145/datagrid-select-last-cell-programatically)